# Why the virtual size still the same after delete a file from container with rm?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, fedora

I would like to know more about Docker. I'm so beginner, very new with this and linux.
My English is not perfect therefore I copied the Terminal output.
I had an image with 516MB VIRTUAL SIZE.
I started the bash in a container and i use wget to download some 26MB data into this. After the downloading I create a image from the container's changes with commit. After that the VIRTUAL SIZE was 542.5MB. That is correct.
After the commit I started again the bash, and I deleted this file.
When i committed the changes the image VIRTUAL SIZE was 542.8MB.

This size does not decreased, instead increased.
Could you tell me the reason?

Local images:

```
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
tester/mytestfedora   latest              c0ca83567bdd        4 seconds ago       516 MB
fedora                 latest              834629358fe2        3 months ago        241.3 MB
```

Using the smallest one and downloading a file:

```
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker run -i -t tester/mytestfedora /bin/bash
bash-4.3# su dockeres
[dockeres@05ef6e284e32 /]$ cd /home/dockeres/downloads/    
[dockeres@05ef6e284e32 downloads]$ wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/827503/0_TEMP/Riverbed.zip
--2015-03-31 19:24:47--  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/827503/0_TEMP/Riverbed.zip
Resolving dl.dropboxusercontent.com (dl.dropboxusercontent.com)... 54.243.97.104, 54.243.80.193, 50.16.185.28, ...
Connecting to dl.dropboxusercontent.com (dl.dropboxusercontent.com)|54.243.97.104|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 26177252 (25M) [application/zip]
Saving to: 'Riverbed.zip'
Riverbed.zip                      100%[==============================================================>]  24.96M  3.66MB/s   in 14s    
2015-03-31 19:25:03 (1.78 MB/s) - 'Riverbed.zip' saved [26177252/26177252]
[dockeres@05ef6e284e32 downloads]$ exit
bash-4.3# exit
```

List the active ones and create a new image from a container's changes:

```
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker ps -all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
05ef6e284e32        tester/mytestfedora:latest   "/bin/bash"         2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 6 seconds ago                       sick_einstein       
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker commit 05ef6e284e32 tester/mytestfedora
f122b12e94a32d477f2f2f18c5a5190a9ad5d349109933da65a0cfeff448c822
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
tester/mytestfedora   latest              f122b12e94a3        5 seconds ago       542.5 MB
fedora                 latest              834629358fe2        3 months ago        241.3 MB
```

Access it again and remove the downloaded file:

```
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker run -i -t tester/mytestfedora /bin/bash
[dockeres@fb5ba36692f0 /]$ cd /home/dockeres/downloads/             
[dockeres@fb5ba36692f0 downloads]$ rm -f Riverbed.zip              
[dockeres@fb5ba36692f0 downloads]$ ls
[dockeres@fb5ba36692f0 downloads]$ exit
bash-4.3# exit
```

List the active ones again and create a new image from a container's changes:

```
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker ps -all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
fb5ba36692f0        tester/mytestfedora:latest   "/bin/bash"         51 seconds ago      Exited (0) 5 seconds ago                       goofy_yalow         
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker commit fb5ba36692f0 tester/mytestfedora
f744e248576d7fa434768a1e1d25625a9654020fe77e12306f304ff5d5ad3e3b
[fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
tester/mytestfedora   latest              f744e248576d        3 seconds ago       542.8 MB
fedora                 latest              834629358fe2        3 months ago        241.3 MB
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Ed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer on comment, as it too big for comment.

Single command

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections \
 && apt-get -qq update \
 && apt-get -qq -y install wget unzip \
 && mkdir /usr/etc \
 && cd /usr/etc \
 && wget -nv -O /tmp/jboss.zip http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip \
 && unzip /tmp/jboss.zip \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Smaller file:

```
$ docker build -t test1 .
$ docker images | grep test1
test1 356 MB
```

Separate commands:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections && apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install wget unzip
RUN wget -nv -O /tmp/jboss.zip http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip
RUN mkdir /usr/etc
RUN cd /usr/etc && unzip /tmp/jboss.zip
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Bigger image:

```
$ docker build -t test2 .
$ docker images | grep test2
test2 510 MB
```

Comment: Dear ISanych! As your sample i created this:
`FROM fedora
RUN su -c 'yum -y install unzip' \
 && su -c 'yum -y install wget' \
 && mkdir /usr/etc \
 && cd /usr/etc \
 && wget -nv -O /tmp/jboss.zip http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip \
 && unzip /tmp/jboss.zip \
 && yum clean all \
 && rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/21/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*`
Now with this code i've reached 442.6 MB! This is optimal because after wget, unzip install without jboss download the size is 281.3 MB. The JBoss unpacked size is: ~160MB(+280=440)! Thank you ISanych, seanmcl!

Comment: by the way, Dockerfile (and commands in container) executed from root unless you will create and specify user, so instead of: su -c 'yum -y install unzip' \ && su -c 'yum -y install wget' better to use: yum -y install unzip wget

Comment: One more thing: 440Mb it is full size of all layers. fedora image is 240Mb - so you layer is 200Mb. And if you will create different images based on fedora this 240Mb image will be shared between all images. Also if you will create couple of other containers based on this one - they will share all layers too. Docker is really cool - good luck with it.

Comment: I see! After this info I get started to create a base, a jdk, and a jboss image build from one after the other. Great to know that! Many thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Docker uses a [union file system](https://docs.docker.com/terms/layer/) for its layers.  Each RUN command creates a new layer, as do commits from running containers.  An image consists of a particular layer and all its ancestor layers.  This is the virtual size.  Thus, the virtual size is monotonically increasing in the layers.  Your wget created a new layer.  Your rm created a new layer, even though the union of files (say, du -hs /) has a smaller size.

Comment: That is why I never add big temp files in run command - I download, unpack and delete files in the same command - most of my dockerfiles have single run command.

Comment: You committed after the file add.  Nothing you do after that will make the image smaller.  [fedora_user@fedora-vm ~]$ docker commit 05ef6e284e32 tester/mytestfedora
f122b12e94a32d477f2f2f18c5a5190a9ad5d349109933da65a0cfeff448c822

Comment: Dear seanmcl, thanks for the light to my head, i understand why it works like that. I commited after the file add. And then i commited again after the file delete. What should i do to make the image smaller?
Dear ISanych, thanks for your advice. I like to get a jboss zip unpack it and delete the zip. I tried this "cd /usr/etc/ && wget http://download.jboss.org/jboss.../jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip && unzip jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip && rm -f jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip" but i've got the same size when i do it step by step in the container. how could i should to concatenate my commands in one command?

Comment: You need to rebuild the image.  Building with commits doesn't scale well.  Make a Dockerfile with the commands.  Then rebuilding is easy.

Comment: @edfromhadria, you show good command, but doing something wrong somewhere else, I've added answer with test as it too big for comment

Comment: I created a Dockerfile.
`FROM fedora
MAINTAINER edfromhadria <edfromhadria@example.com>
RUN su -c 'yum -y install unzip' && su -c 'yum -y install wget' && mkdir /usr/etc && cd /usr/etc/ && wget http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip && unzip jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip && rm -rf jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip`
This image size is 609.5 MB. Without Dockerfile the images size is: 610.2 MB. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my English is not good, I used machine translation

If you need to remove a large amount of space in the container, then you can consider the following methods.

You can use `docker export` and `docker import` to get rid of the history layer of old images.

Suppose you now have a container B running in old image

A. and you have deleted some files in container
B. Now you need to export this container B to tar and import back a new image
C. `docker export -o your.tar containerID`
`docker import your.tar new-image`

You will notice that both the tar file and the new image C are much smaller than the old image.

Comment: It had better to remove non-english characters.