# How to use cp command in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to decrease the number of layers used in my Dockerfile.
So I want to combine the `COPY` commands in a `RUN cp`.

- dependencies

  - folder1
  - file1
  - file2
- Dockerfile

The following below commands work which I want to combine using a single `RUN cp` command

```
COPY ./dependencies/file1 /root/.m2

COPY ./dependencies/file2 /root/.sbt/

COPY ./dependencies/folder1 /root/.ivy2/cache
```

This following below command says No such file or directory present error. Where could I be going wrong ?

```
RUN cp ./dependencies/file1 /root/.m2 && \
    cp ./dependencies/file2 /root/.sbt/ && \
    cp ./dependencies/folder1 /root/.ivy2/cache
```

Comment: [`RUN` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run)  and [`COPY` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) do different things. We cannot replace a `COPY ...`  with a `RUN cp ...`. --- Why do you want to replace the multple `COPY`s with a single directive anyway?

Comment: Wanted to lessen the layers currently my Dockerfile has 15+ layers

Comment: ... so? What's the problem with that?

Comment: The image size is humungous due to it. See this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380738/why-the-virtual-size-still-the-same-after-delete-a-file-from-container-with-rm

Comment: This has nothing to do with the layer size. The problem in the post you linked is that we cannot "remove" files form the final image size when they were added in an earlier layer.

Comment: If you really want to replace the muptile layers generated by the mutliple `COPY`s, then I recommend to either follow [Hans Killian's approach and replicate the needed file structure on the host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74969858/4216641) or use a tool that allows more fine-granular control of layer creation, e.g. [buildah (`buildah.io`)](https://buildah.io/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

The [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) is used to copy files from your host to your container. So, when you run

```
COPY ./dependencies/file1 /root/.m2
COPY ./dependencies/file2 /root/.sbt/
COPY ./dependencies/folder1 /root/.ivy2/cache
```

Docker will look for `file1`, `file2`, and `folder1` **on your host**.

However, when you do it with [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run), the commands are executed **inside the container**, and `./dependencies/file1` (and so on) does not exist in your container yet, which leads to `file not found` error.

In short, `COPY` and `RUN` are not interchangeable.

---

#### How to fix

If you don't want to use multiple `COPY` commands, you can use one `COPY` to copy all files from your host to your container, then use the `RUN` command to move them to the proper location.

To avoid copying unnecessary files, use [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file). For example:

**.dockerignore**

```
./dependencies/no-need-file
./dependencies/no-need-directory/
```

**Dockerfile**

```
COPY ./dependencies/ /root/
RUN mv ./dependencies/file1 /root/.m2 && \
    mv ./dependencies/file2 /root/.sbt/ && \
    mv ./dependencies/folder1 /root/.ivy2/cache
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that.

`COPY` copies from the host to the image.

`RUN cp` copies from a location in the image to another location in the image.

To get it all into a single COPY statement, you can create the file structure you want on the host and then use `tar` to make it a single file. Then when you `COPY` or `ADD` that tar file, Docker will unpack it and put the files in the correct place. But with the current structure your files have on the host, it's not possible to do in a single COPY command.

Answer (score 0):

You a re missing final slash in `/root/.ivy2/cache/`

Comment: This won't fix the issue. `COPY ...` cannot be replaced by `RUN cp ...`.

Comment: @Turing85 i didn't notice RUN and cp  in the same line! My bad, thank you