# Unable to delete pypoetry cache in dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, python-poetry

I'm trying to delete the artifacts and cache directories generated by poetry to reduce the docker image size. Though --no-cache works for cache but artifacts still takes too much space. I'm doing the following in my dockerfile:

```
RUN rm -rf ~/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts
```

But when I exec into the image I can still see artifacts directory and its still taking up significant space.

Comment: You can add pypoetry cache directory to your .dockerignore file

Comment: @Fcmam5 I think that will not work as the cache is populated while installing dependencies while building the docker image.

Comment: The `~` directory may not be well-defined, since the Docker environment frequently doesn't have a home directory; does an absolute path work better?  Also note that this won't actually make the image smaller ([Why the virtual size still the same after delete a file from container with rm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380738/why-the-virtual-size-still-the-same-after-delete-a-file-from-container-with-rm)) unless you can put the `rm` into the same command that generates the files to start with.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you, that worked. I used `&&` and then `rm -rf`